# javascript class member is undefined in local function

Tags: javascript, class, socket.io, member

This is part of my program code.

```
        makeQRCode : function() {
            var URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

            this.socket = io.connect(URL + '/socket', {'force new connection': true});
            console.log(this.myMaker);  //print Maker's functions

            this.socket.on('connect', function(){
                console.log('connect');
                console.log(URL);   //print 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
                //console.log(this.myMaker);    //how can I call myMaker In this function
            });
        }
```

Since 'this' in socket.io function indicate 'socket', cannot access class member.
How can I access class member in there.

Comment: ...and just about 100 others. This post on my blog may also help [*You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)*.

Comment: I googled with uncorrect word. Thanks alot @T.J.Crowder. do I have to do something to close this question?

Comment: Glad that helped. :-) It's already closed, but if you don't think it'll help people to find this info in the future, you can delete it. (Probably go ahead and do that, there are a *huge* number of these already.)